# How to write a complicated query in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I use MySQL on Linux. My table is about 8,000,000 rows. The table has indexes on `advertiser_id, activity_date` and `activity_date, advertiser_id, activity_type`.

The table looks like:

```
activity_date        advertiser_id activity_type message
2014-06-01 00:00:16  80149         46            open service                
2014-06-01 00:00:16  80149         11            Set Bid Management automatic
2014-06-01 00:01:49  80149         47            close service               
2014-06-01 00:01:49  80149         12            Set Bid Management 
2014-06-01 00:03:17  37            12            Lowered daily budget              
2014-06-01 00:03:17  59            46            open service  bid                           
2014-06-01 00:03:17  59            14            Raised daily budget automatic
```

The table is an activity log. Activity 46 is to start a service and 47 is to end this service. Between doing activity 46 and activity 47, all the activity should be automatic. I want to look at a particular time to see whether the users' activity is automatic or not.  For one user, if he/she has one automatic activity, this user is automatically.  I do not know how to do it; I wrote a SQL query which does not do what I need.  Is there anyone that can help?

```
SET @prevdate := CURDATE()- INTERVAL 1 DAY;
select advertiser_id,CASE WHEN count(*) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS is_bid_optimize
from table1
WHERE activity_type = 46
        AND activity_date <= @prevdate
        AND activity_date > (@prevdate-INTERVAL 90 DAY)
GROUP BY advertiser_id;
```

Comment: Its unclear what you want coud you edit your question with the desired results?

Answer (score 0):

For the given user and time find the most recent activity which is a 46 or a 47.  If it is 46 the user is "automatic".  If it is 47 the user is not "automatic".

There will be users who do not have any 46 or 47 records.  These will return and empty resultset and the application will have to interpret these appropriately.

If activities can arrive so quickly that the 46 and 47 rows both have the same `activity_date` values this won't work.  You will have to try a different approach, increase the resolution of `activity_date` or use a sequential integer column as a proxy.